# How to change the Json save file content in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am binding a data from database to JSON file. by using the code in code behind file.

```
string JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datatable);
```

by default the data table are store in to json file in this format. I have attached code given below.

```
[
  {
    "ProductID": 17,
    "ProductName": "Alice Mutton"
  },
  {
    "ProductID": 3,
    "ProductName": "Aniseed Syrup"
  },
  {
    "ProductID": 40,
    "ProductName": "Boston Crab Meat"
  }]
```

I want to change this save format to by like this.

```
{

  "from_ProductName": "Alice Mutton",// Too Tip
  "to_ProductName": "Boston Crab Meat",// Too Tip
  "column_names": [
    "ProductName",
    "ProductID"
  ],

  "data": [
    [
      "Alice Mutton",
      17
    ],
    [
      "Aniseed Syrup",
      2
    ],
    [
      "Boston Crab Meat",
      250.1
    ]]
}
```

and this datas should come by database.

can any one tell me how to achieve the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this simple example, you can run it and you will see exactly the same result as you want.

First, I created class to represent your DB object

```
private class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created this method to get what you want

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var originalJson = "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"ProductID\": 17,\r\n    \"ProductName\": \"Alice Mutton\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ProductID\": 3,\r\n    \"ProductName\": \"Aniseed Syrup\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ProductID\": 40,\r\n    \"ProductName\": \"Boston Crab Meat\"\r\n  }] ";
    var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(originalJson);
    var resultObject = new
    {
        from_ProductName = products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductName).FirstOrDefault().ProductName,
        to_ProductName = products.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductName).FirstOrDefault().ProductName,
        column_names = new List<string> { nameof(Product.ProductName), nameof(Product.ProductID) },
        data = products.Select(p => new List<object> { p.ProductName, p.ProductID })
    };

    var saveFormat = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultObject);    
}
```

Then the pretty print result looks like this:

```
{
    "from_ProductName": "Alice Mutton",
    "to_ProductName": "Boston Crab Meat",
    "column_names": ["ProductName", "ProductID"],
    "data": [["Alice Mutton", 17], 
             ["Aniseed Syrup", 3],
             ["Boston Crab Meat", 40] ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your  model class should look like :

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string from_ProductName { get; set; }
    public string to_ProductName { get; set; }
    public List<string> column_names { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> data { get; set; }
}
```

Test method:

```
public void TestCreateModel()
{
  RootObject rootObject = new RootObject();
  rootObject.from_ProductName = "Prod1";
  rootObject.to_ProductName = "Prod2";
  rootObject.column_names = new List<string>(){"ProductName", "ProductID"};
  var dataList = new List<object>() {"Alice Mutton," + 17};
  var dataList1 = new List<object>() {"Aniseed Syrup," + 2};
  var dataList2 = new List<object>() {"Boston Crab Meat," + 250.1};
  rootObject.data = new List<List<object>>() {dataList, dataList1, dataList2};

  string JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject);
}
```

Result:
[image]

Easy way to genarate model class from json is use simple tool like http://json2csharp.com/. Basically now you trying serialize only List of `List<object>`, change it and use model class like this above.

Comment: string JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datatable); using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/mew12.json"), true))
                {
                    w.WriteLine(JSONString); 
                }

Comment: here how can i use enitity